# How to style the thumb of wpf slider?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I read about style here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278073(v=VS.95).aspx

I created a UserControl with slider and UserControl.Resources section. I paste the thumb style but some tag are not recognized like vsm:VisualStateManager (I'm using VS2010) why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the documentation for Silverlight.  You probably want the documentation for WPF:

- [Slider Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753256%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

**Edit:**

Just to be clear, if you are using Silverlight, you should use Silverlight templates and styles; if you are using WPF, you should use WPF templates and styles.

In any case, the `VisualStateManager` is a full-fledged part of both Silverlight4 and WPF4, so if you see a template with the "vsm:" namespace, the simplest option is to just remove the prefix where-ever you see it.